# How to install a fresh Android 2.3 to my Spice Mi280?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, operating-system

I want to install fresh 2.3 Android OS on my Spice Mi280 over my previous installation. How can I do that?

[image: Spice Mi280 - About Phone]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want a fresh installation and no update, then a factory reset would be sufficient.

Comment: I want to update the ROM.

Comment: According to your screenshot, you already running Android 2.3

Comment: You're on 2.3.4, so 2.3 would be a downgrade.  Why do you want to "upgrade" your ROM?